# Getting access denied with GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl()..?

Tags: c, winapi

I’m attempting to check the rights on a particular file for a specific
trustee and am using the win32 API GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl().  When
the file is accessible by a domain group, the function
returns 5 (Access Denied) when a local account (admin or other) is
used to execute the function.

These three statements summarize the behavior I am seeing with
GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl():

- When domain group has rights to the file and the program runs under a
  local account: Access Denied.
- When domain group has rights to the file and the program runs
  under a domain account or Local System: Success
- When domain group doesn't have rights to the file and the
  program runs under any account: Success

Does anyone know the reason behind this?  It looks to me like this is
related to Active Directory security.  What settings could affect this
and what would be a good way to debug this?

Also, I've heard that GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl() may be generally problematic and to use AccessCheck() instead.  However I need to be able to take an arbitrary SID and check it's access against a file and since AccessCheck() requires an impersonation token I don't know how I could greate a token out of an arbitrary SID...  Any ideas?  Thanks

Bob

Answer (score 3):

I have in C# used and it works well for me.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace DACL
{
    class Class1
    {
        private enum MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE_OPERATION
        {
            NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE,
            TRUSTEE_IS_IMPERSONATE
        }

        private enum TRUSTEE_FORM
        {
            TRUSTEE_IS_SID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_NAME,
            TRUSTEE_BAD_FORM,
            TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_SID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_NAME
        }

        private enum TRUSTEE_TYPE
        {
            TRUSTEE_IS_UNKNOWN,
            TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
            TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP,
            TRUSTEE_IS_DOMAIN,
            TRUSTEE_IS_ALIAS,
            TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP,
            TRUSTEE_IS_DELETED,
            TRUSTEE_IS_INVALID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_COMPUTER
        }

        private struct TRUSTEE
        {
            public IntPtr pMultipleTrustee;
            public MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE_OPERATION MultipleTrusteeOperation;
            public TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm;
            public TRUSTEE_TYPE TrusteeType;
            public IntPtr ptstrName;
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern void BuildTrusteeWithSid(
            ref TRUSTEE pTrustee,
            byte[] sid
        );

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(byte[] pacl, ref TRUSTEE pTrustee, ref uint pAccessRights);

        public bool HasAccess(SecurityIdentifier sid)
        {
            DiscretionaryAcl dacl = <DACL from somewhere>;

            byte[] daclBuffer = new byte[dacl.BinaryLength];
            dacl.GetBinaryForm(daclBuffer, 0);

            byte[] sidBuffer = new byte[sid.BinaryLength];
            sid.GetBinaryForm(sidBuffer, 0);

            TRUSTEE t = new TRUSTEE();
            BuildTrusteeWithSid(ref t, sidBuffer);

            uint access = 0;
            uint hr = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(daclBuffer, ref t, ref access);

            int i = Marshal.Release(t.ptstrName);

            return ((access & <Desired Access>) == <Desired Access>) ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i don't have much experience with this -- how do you know the values for dacl, as well as the desired access uint value? Which resource would you refer to, to find out those things?

Answer (score 2):

- if domain group have right to the
  file, this function has to access
  the active directory to enumerate
  the group membership of the trustee
  ( at least if it is a domain user ).
  If your program is running under
  local account, then this account
  don't have right to access the
  active directory, hence the error
  return code.
- domain account and Local System have
  access to the active directory.
  Local system is the computer account
  in the active directory( computers
  are like users in AD).
- If no domain group has access to the
  file, the function don't have to
  check with the active directory. So
  local users succeed too.