# Check if everyone may read/write to a directory

Tags: delphi, acl

We are facing the problem, that different user groups shall be able to read and write files from a common data directory (e.g. c:\ProgramData\xyz).

The data is written from different sources e.g. a service writes files into it and a user shall be able to change it's content later on.

The problem now is that this only works if "everybody" is allowed to read/write/change 
files in that directory (und subdirs).

What I want to check in the installer is if all users are allowed to do so aka. check if the "every users" group (or "Jeder" group in german) is in the access list. 
I have only basic knowledge about ACL and can change that in the explorer but I would need a few lines of code which push me into the right direction (in Delphi).

many thanks
  Mike

Comment: Check this link at Alexey Dynnikov's [webpage](http://www.aldyn.ru/demos/0008/1.html). It might give you some hints.

Comment: What do you actually want to do. The recommended practice is for your installer to set the ACL on your app's subfolder of ProgramData. You don't check anything in the installer. You simply create a new folder and apply the ACL with appropriate permissions.

Comment: @david: the directory is already there - the service/server is basically an addon to an existing installation. The installer does not create any data directory.

Comment: Only the installer is going to have sufficient rights to create the directory and give it the appropriate ACL. Because only the installer runs elevated.

Comment: @david: This is what I'm trying to do. My (the second) installer shall especially verify that there is writing/reading possible for everyone.

Comment: @mrabat I still cannot understand why you installer doesn't just create the ACL at install time. Why do you need to check anything. Just add the ACL and be done with it.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I think he's just a novice at this and is confused.

Comment: @David: The user may override that value at any time afterwards also from a second source. (and thats the normal case!). The installer bascially only creates that directory by default. Anyway the only place where I can check on that directory is basically on my own home brewn setup and the service itself and I want to insert that check in both modules. Anyway I was asking for a piece of code which shows how to do that. Pherhaps the easiest way is to set the permission is via a batch file and icacls .... opinions? The part left open is checking the permissions in Delphi code....

Comment: Any decent installer will assign ACLs for you. I don't see why you need to check anything. You just add your ACL.

Comment: @David: Users will and may change that value. The installer only knows some defaults (and actually adds them). The setting (data path) is stored in a database and is not avail to the InnoSetup installer... Users have the possibility to change that directory on a later time using our own home brewn administration tool. So I want to check that on both modules -> installer and the service.

Comment: After you have added your ACL, the users may change it. How are you going to defend against that? You are being too paranoid. The users could delete the folder. How do you stop that?

Comment: @David: I cannot stop them to delete the folder I just want to make sure that my service (http server) will flawlessly interact with a desktop application. At least I want to log a message and quit the service on startup if the rights are not defined (and within the desktop application) so users or our technicians can take action.

Comment: But that will happen for free. Because you'll get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` when you attempt to do anything in the folder.

Comment: @David: It will eventually sometime but we use some "file type semaphore" as well to hinder two systems using the same file which also results in an Access_Denied exception when opening that file. Anyway reading files would be allowed but changing them normally not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a Delphi but WinAPI question. Delphi doesn't have any special facilities to make this easier AFAIK.

[Getting information from an ACL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says you need to do [GetSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on an open handle, then [GetEffectiveRightsFromACL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on an ACL you get.

You specify a [trustee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379636%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which can be by name, but better use SID. Name for "Everyone" can change, but there's a special SID for it which is valid on any PC, google it. Okay, here it is: "(S-1–1–0)". Or you can use [CreateWellKnownSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and give it [WinWorldSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the same SID (more proper but longer way).

All of that from five minutes of googling so watch out for mistakes.

Alright, here's some code.

```
function ConvertStringSidToSid(StringSid: PWideChar; var Sid: PSID): boolean; stdcall; external advapi32 name 'ConvertStringSidToSidW';

function AclGetEffectiveRights(const path, sid: string): cardinal;
var h: THandle; //handle to our directory
  err: integer;
  dacl: PACL; //access control list for the object
  secdesc: pointer;
  tr: TRUSTEE;
  bsid: PSid;
begin
  Result := 0;
 //Open directory
  h := CreateFile(PChar(path), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL or FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
    //we need FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS to open a directory
  if h=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOsError();
  try

    bsid := nil;
   //Query access control list for a directory -- the list you see in the properties box
    err := GetSecurityInfo(h, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
      nil, nil, @dacl, nil, secdesc);
      //GetSecurityInfo can return many things but we only need DACL,
      //and we are required to also get a security descriptor
    if err<>ERROR_SUCCESS then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot retrieve DACL: error %d',[err]);
    try
     //Convert string sid to binary sid
      if not ConvertStringSidToSid(PChar(sid), bsid) then
        RaiseLastOsError();

     //Query effective rights for a trustee
      BuildTrusteeWithSid(@tr, bsid);
      err := GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(dacl^, tr, Result);
      if err<>ERROR_SUCCESS then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot calculate effective rights: error %d',[err]);
    finally
     //Documentation says to free some resources this way when we're done with it.
      LocalFree(NativeUint(bsid));
      LocalFree(NativeUint(secdesc));
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(h);
  end;
end;
```

It's used like this:

```
var rights,test: cardinal;
rights := AclGetEffectiveRights('C:\My\Folder','S-1-1-0');
//List rights you want tested
test := FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY + FILE_ADD_FILE + FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY
  + FILE_READ_EA + FILE_WRITE_EA + FILE_TRAVERSE + FILE_DELETE_CHILD;
Result := (rights and test) = test;
```

Might not work; gives ACCESS_DENIED on my PC but that's probably because of my [complicated domain situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364096/getting-access-denied-with-geteffectiverightsfromacl). Anyway that's something for a start.

Comment: That's what I googled too.. but since I don't have any experience using that knowledge - Microsoft did a great job here doing stuff like this quite complicated.

Comment: Since Windows 10 update 1903 the GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl always returns with a 1355 error (ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN). It's a local computer with no domain controler whatsoever and a local directory. Anyone has a clue what problem that may be?

Answer (score 0):

So.. The above version worked... until Windows Update 1903 hit me and GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl always resulted in an error ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN (which is obscure since there is no Domain whatsoever involved here).
So I needed to switch to the following procedure:

```
// ###########################################
// ### translated and extended from https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-geteffectiverightsfromacla

procedure DisplayAccessMask(Mask : ACCESS_MASK );
begin
{
      // This evaluation of the ACCESS_MASK is an example. 
      // Applications should evaluate the ACCESS_MASK as necessary.

}
   if (((Mask and GENERIC_ALL) = GENERIC_ALL)
      or ((Mask and FILE_ALL_ACCESS) = FILE_ALL_ACCESS)) 
   then
   begin
        OutputDebugString( 'Full control');
        exit;
   end;

   if (((Mask and GENERIC_READ) = GENERIC_READ)
      or ((Mask and FILE_GENERIC_READ) = FILE_GENERIC_READ)) 
   then
       OutputDebugString( 'Read');

   if (((Mask and GENERIC_WRITE) = GENERIC_WRITE)
      or ((Mask and FILE_GENERIC_WRITE) = FILE_GENERIC_WRITE))
   then
         OutputDebugString('Write');

   if (((Mask and GENERIC_EXECUTE) = GENERIC_EXECUTE)
      or ((Mask and FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE) = FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE))
   then
       OutputDebugString('Execute');

end;

function CheckMask( MASK : ACCESS_MASK; refMask : ACCESS_MASK ) : boolean;
var msk : ACCESS_MASK;
begin
     msk := 0;

     if (((Mask and GENERIC_READ) = GENERIC_READ)
      or ((Mask and FILE_GENERIC_READ) = FILE_GENERIC_READ)) 
     then
         msk := msk or FILE_GENERIC_READ;

   if (((Mask and GENERIC_WRITE) = GENERIC_WRITE)
      or ((Mask and FILE_GENERIC_WRITE) = FILE_GENERIC_WRITE))
   then
       msk := msk or FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;

   if (((Mask and GENERIC_EXECUTE) = GENERIC_EXECUTE)
      or ((Mask and FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE) = FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE))
   then
       msk := msk or FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE;

   Result := (msk and refMask) = refMask;
end;

function GetAccess(hAuthzClient :AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE; psd : PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) : BOOL;
var AccessRequest : AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST;
    AccessReply : AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY;
    buffer : Array[0..1023] of Byte;
begin
     FillChar(AccessRequest, sizeof(AccessRequest), 0);
     FillChar(AccessReply, sizeof(AccessReply), 0);
     FillChar(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

     AccessRequest.DesiredAccess := MAXIMUM_ALLOWED;
     AccessRequest.PrincipalSelfSid := nil;
     AccessRequest.ObjectTypeList := nil;
     AccessRequest.ObjectTypeListLength := 0;
     AccessRequest.OptionalArguments := nil;

     AccessReply.ResultListLength := 1;
     AccessReply.GrantedAccessMask := PACCESS_MASK( LongWord(@Buffer[0])); 
     AccessReply.Error := PDWORD( LongWord( AccessReply.GrantedAccessMask ) + sizeof(Access_Mask));

     Result := AuthzAccessCheck( 0,
                          hAuthzClient,
                          @AccessRequest,
                          0,
                          psd,
                          nil,
                          0,
                          @AccessReply,
                          nil);

     if Result then
     begin
          DisplayAccessMask( AccessReply.GrantedAccessMask^ );
          Result := CheckMask( AccessReply.GrantedAccessMask^, FILE_GENERIC_WRITE or FILE_GENERIC_READ );
     end
     else
         RaiseLastOSError;
end;

function ConvertStringSidToSid(StringSid: PWideChar; var Sid: PSID): boolean; stdcall; external advapi32 name 'ConvertStringSidToSidW';

function ConvertNameToBinarySid(pAccountName : PCHAR): PSID ;
var pDomainName : PChar;
    dwDomainNameSize : DWord;
    aSID : PSID;
    dwSIDSIZE : DWORD;
    sidType : SID_NAME_USE;
begin
     pDomainName := nil;
     dwDomainNameSize := 0;
     aSID := nil;

     LookupAccountName( nil, pAccountName, aSID, dwSIDSIZE, pDomainName, dwDomainNameSize, sidType);
     aSid := Pointer( LocalAlloc( LPTR, dwSIDSIZE*sizeof(char)) );
     pDomainName := Pointer( LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwDomainNameSize*sizeof(char)) );
     if not LookupAccountName( nil, pAccountName, aSID, dwSIDSIZE, pDomainName, dwDomainNameSize, sidType) then
     begin
          LocalFree( Cardinal(aSID) );
          Result := nil;
     end
     else
     begin
          Result := aSid;
     end;

     LocalFree( Cardinal(pDomainName) );
end;

function GetEffectiveRightsForSID(hManager :AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE;
                                   psd : PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR; 
                                   sid : PChar) : BOOL;
var asid : PSID;
    bResult : BOOL;
    unusedID : LUID;
    hAuthzClientContext : AUTHZ_CLIENT_CONTEXT_HANDLE;
begin
     Result := False;
     asid := nil;
     hAuthzClientContext := 0;
     FillChar(unusedID, sizeof(unusedID), 0);

     if not ConvertStringSidToSid(sid, asid) then
        RaiseLastOsError();
//     asid := ConvertNameToBinarySid('rabatscher');

     if asid = nil then
        RaiseLastOSError;
     try
        if asid <> nil then
        begin
             bResult := AuthzInitializeContextFromSid( 0, aSid, hManager, nil, unusedId, nil, @hAuthzClientContext );
             try
                if bResult then
                   Result := GetAccess(hAuthzClientContext, psd);
             finally
                    if hAuthzClientContext <> 0 then
                       AuthzFreeContext(hAuthzClientContext);
             end;
        end;
     finally
            if asid <> nil then
               LocalFree(LongWord(asid));
     end;
end;

function UseAuthzSolution( psd : PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR; const sid : string = 'S-1-1-0') : boolean;
var hManager : AUTHZ_RESOURCE_MANAGER_HANDLE;
    bResult : BOOL;
    pSid : PChar;
begin
     bResult := AuthzInitializeResourceManager(AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_AUDIT,
                nil, nil, nil, nil, @hManager);
     if bResult then
     begin
          pSid := PChar(sid);
          bResult := GetEffectiveRightsForSID(hManager, psd, psid);
          AuthzFreeResourceManager(hManager);
     end;

     Result := bResult;
end;

function GetSecurityInfo(handle: THandle; ObjectType: SE_OBJECT_TYPE;
         SecurityInfo: SECURITY_INFORMATION; ppsidOwner, ppsidGroup: PPSID; ppDacl, ppSacl: PACL;
         var pSecurityDescriptor: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR): DWORD; stdcall; external 'ADVAPI32.DLL' name 'GetSecurityInfo'; {use localfree to release ppSecurityDescriptor}


function CheckDirectoryAccess( path : string ) : boolean;
var dw : DWORD;
    apacl : PACL;
    psd : PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
    apSID : PSID;
    h : THandle;    
begin
     try
        apSID := nil;

        //Open directory
        h := CreateFile(PChar(path), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
                     OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL or FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);

        //we need FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS to open a directory
        if h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then 
           RaiseLastOsError();
        try
           //Query access control list for a directory -- the list you see in the properties box
           dw := GetSecurityInfo(h, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION or OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                  nil, nil, @apacl, nil, psd);

           if dw <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
              RaiseLastOSError;

           try
              Result := UseAuthzSolution(psd);
           finally
                  if apSID <> nil then
                     LocalFree(NativeUint(apSID));

                  LocalFree(NativeUint(psd));
           end;
        finally
               CloseHandle(h);
        end;
     except
           on E : Exception do
           begin
                Result := False;
           end;
     end;
end;
```

Note that there are a few changes so the procedure works:
GetSecurityInfo (from the above procedure) needs the parameter DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION or OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION (not only DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION) otherwise you get an Error 87 in AuthzAccessCheck!

In addition you need to check out the JWA headers from the jedi library.

Hope that helps other people too.